# Fast memory allocation for real time data acquisition

Tags: c++, memory-management

I have a range of sensors connected to a PC that measure various physical parameters, like force, rotational speed and temperature. These sensors continuously produce samples at some sample rate. A sample consists of a timestamp and the measured dimension itself; the sample rates are in magnitudes of single-digit kilohertz (i.e., somewhere between 1 and 9000 samples per second).

The PC is supposed to read and store these samples during a given period of time. Afterwards the collected data is further treated and evaluated.

What would be a sensible way to buffer the samples? At some realistic setup the acquisition could easily gather a couple of megabytes per second. Also paging could be critical in case memory is allocated fast but needs swapping upon write.

I could think of a threaded approach where a separate thread allocates and manages a pool of (locked, so non-swappable) memory chunks. Given there are always enough of these chunks pre-allocated, further allocation would only block (in case other processes' pages have to be swapped out before) this memory pool's thread and the acquisition could proceed without interruption.

This basically is a conceptual question. Yet, to be more specific:

- It should only rely on portable features, like POSIX. Features out Qt's universe is fine, too.
- The sensors can be interfaced in various ways. IP is one possibility. Usually the sensors are directly connected to the PC via local links (RS232, USB, extension cards and such). That is, fast enough.
- The timestamps are mostly applied by the acquisition hardware itself if it is capable in doing so, to avoid jitter over network etc.

## Thinking it over

Should I really worry? Apparently the problem diverts into three scenarios:

1. There is only little data collected at all. It can easily be buffered in one large pre-allocated buffer.
2. Data is collected slowly. Allocating the buffers on the fly is perfectly fine.
3. There is so much data acquired at high sample rates. Then allocation is not the problem because the buffer will eventually overflow anyway. The problem is rather how to transfer the data from the memory buffer to permanent storage fast enough.

Comment: What operating system are you targetting ?

Comment: Take a look at ring buffers. They're commonly used for real time buffering of data.

Comment: What is the interface with the sensors?  IP/network?  Where is the timestamp applied, at the sensor or after trasport to the PC?

Comment: Allocate your buffers once and re-use them.  Allocation and deallocation of memory is a common bottleneck for performance critical systems.

Comment: Couple of megabytes per second is nothing. Before you want to worry about how to allocate memory effectively, you should be worried how to dump the data to disk effectively. If you don't hit any disk issue, memory should be the least of your concerns.

Comment: Dumping it to disk is of no worry, as this can be done afterwards without real time needs. Although thinking about that makes me start wondering myself if I should actually worry.

Comment: If you can keep all the data in memory (i.e. it is one relatively short measurement), then just allocate all the memory you need in advance any way you feel comfortable and forget about it

Comment: Typical double buffer will do: when software is dumping buffer B into disk, hardware is writing to buffer A. When software finishes dumping, it acknowledge hardware to switch buffer at the next gap between acquisition. When hardware have successfully switched, it acknowledges software to start dumping whenever possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea for solving this type of problems can be as follows:

Separate the problem into 2 or more processes depending what you need to do with your data:

- Acquirer
- Analyzer (if you want to process data in real time)
- Writer

Store data in a circular buffer in shared memory (I recommend using boost::interprocess).

Acquirer will continuously read data from the device and store it in a shared memory. In the meantime, once is enough data read for doing any analysis, the Analyzer will start processing it. It can store results into another circular buffer shared memory  if needed. Also in the meantime Reader will read the data from shared memory (acquired or already processed) and store it in the output file.

You need to make sure all the processes are synchronized properly so that they do their job simultaneously and you don't lose the data (the data is not being overwritten before is processed or saved into output file).